# Using ANY operator together with string functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to build a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE Charindex(ANY(SELECT City FROM Cities),T1ADDRESS)>0
```

As i understand, the `ANY` operator cannot stay as SQL functions argument. So, what is the alternative?

Suppose I want to write a UDF that returns 1 or 0 dependent on one input argument *Address*. How do I do this without `for` loop operator and without accessing to `SELECT City FROM Cities` array by index, as it can be done easily in the procedural languages?

Comment: You should not use functions on columns in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @LukasEder T-SQL for SQL Server

Comment: I think you are probably looking for the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: Note that both the `LIKE` operator and UDFs aren't great for performance. Would be useful if the city was normalised out of the address.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a `JOIN`?

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1
INNER JOIN CITIES
    ON T1ADDRESS LIKE '%' + City + '%'
```

Not sure about performance however...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE Charindex in (SELECT '%'+City+'%' FROM Cities)
```

which address the ANY problem but not everything you asked for.

Comment: Not, the IN operator finds exact matchings, but I want to find a substring matching

Comment: updated for substring problem. It is part of the solution though, I did not get your whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
SELECT 
              * 
    FROM 
            T1 
    WHERE
        EXISTS
        (
            SELECT City FROM Cities WHERE T1.T1ADDRESS LIKE '%' + City + '%' 
        )
```